# Update list item in another web application from event receiver

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am trying to programmatically create a folder in Document library in **another web application** from item event receiver. the following is the code I am using:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb web = properties.Web;
        Guid currListID = properties.ListId;
        int currListItemID = properties.ListItemId;


        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb elevWeb = site.OpenWeb(web.ID))    
                    {
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        elevWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList elevList = elevWeb.Lists[currListID];
                        SPListItem elevCurrItem = elevList.GetItemById(currListItemID);



                        createProjectFolder(elevCurrItem.Title);



                        elevWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        base.ItemAdded(properties);
    }


private void createProjectFolder(string projectTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
          {
              using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(SPSiteUrl))
              {
                  spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                  using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                  {
                      spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                      SPList spList = spWeb.Lists[destListName];


                       SPListItem newFolder = spList.Items.Add("", SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, projectTitle);
                       newFolder.Update();


                      spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                  }
                  spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
              }
          });


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

but I am receiving the following error:

{"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(Guid webId, String strListName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetListByName(String strListName, Boolean bThrowException)
   at ER_EPMProjectCenterList.ER_ProjectCenterItemAdded.ER_ProjectCenterItemAdded.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__4()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)

I know that I am receiving this error because I am trying to access list cross domain. Is there any work around to achieve that. Please I need your help.

Comment: Does the app pool account your current web app has permission in other web application? I think error is quite clear.

Comment: Yes it has full control access

Comment: ok..did you try  removing spsecurity RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: Yes I did, same error message. And I tried with CSOM too but same error.

Comment: what kind of event receiver it is?can you update your question with all details..

Comment: SPItemEventReceiver on ItemAdded I updated my post.

Comment: Where is SPSiteUrl defined? I assume it contains the url of the other webapp?

Comment: @Verthosa Yes it contain the url of the other web application